# How to Virtualize iOS on a Windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7, ios-simulator, virtualization

I'm trying to learn to code in Objective C, but I am not ready to commit to purchasing a Mac for just this purpose, seeing as I have a good Dell laptop. My computer has VMware installed on it, but I do not know how to actually go through the steps, and I do not know what I need to install or purchase(if absolutely necessary). Eventually, I hope to get a Mac, so this won't be needed, but until then, I want to find a way to compile Objective C so I can actually learn how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Apple's licensing prevents you from running OS X (and thus, the iOS simulator) on non-Apple hardware, so unfortunately you'll have to get a Mac first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/), [Developing iOS app on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12771361), [iOS and Android development on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4993059), and [more](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site:meta.stackoverflow.com+ios+windowws#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+ios+development+windows&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+ios+development+windows)

Comment: It prevents you from running a *standard* copy of OS X. Through VMWare or virtualbox, one can run a specially modified copy of OS X. Note however that it often runs far slower than it would on an equivalent mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is technically possible, I'll tell you from experience:

To run Xcode and the iOS Simulator, you will need to have MacOS running. Oficially it only runs on Apple Hardware, buuut, you can always use virtualizers and Hackintosh. There are plenty of good tutorials online if you choose this method.

My advice: **DON'T do it!**

When I started to develop iOS apps, I had a Windows PC, but after trying lots of different approaches to virtualize MacOS, with none I had great results. I bought a MacBook on a sale, and it's just a better iOS development experience overall. It's priceless not to have to deal with driver searching and compatibility issues.

Comment: I did the same; the virtualization and hackintosh stuff works, but not at all well. Save yourself the headache, and buy a mac.

Comment: I guess. Not the answer I hoped for, but thanks for preventing future headaches

Comment: Just got a Mac Mini to program on from ebay... You are correct. So much better than any other option!

Comment: agreed - if you want to develop Mac apps, use the Mac platform - all the tools and support have been developed as such - it doesn't make sense to attempt otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

First virtualize MacOS X, inside then iOS with XCode. See http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, you need to virtualize OSX inside you Windows, and then use XCode as the other stated, however it doesen't work with nearly all AMD CPU's but i think Dell uses mostly Intel. And a Mac costs alot. For example i don't have money for one, the cheapest one costs $1,600 where i come from, but **if** you are going to get a Mac, i would wait for that.

But they really are expensive, and i only need a Macbook for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming you already have the mac installation image or vmware file]
Sadly Vmware does not include support for mac in it's latest versions
So you'll have to patch(aka Vmware Unlocker for OS X) it.
Follow this link http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/files/file/20-vmware-unlocker-for-os-x/ (you'll be required to set up an account)
Or alternatively you can download the VirtualBox(https://www.virtualbox.org/)
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualbox instead of VMWare. If it does'nt work, install the extension pack for virtualbox.