# IOS7 Simulator for Windows

Tags: windows, ios7, ios-simulator

I want to test the browser response on IPhone for my web based app. Can I install the simulator on windows (7 or 8)? Where can I download IOS7 Simulator for Windows8?

Comment: mate i don't think this is possible

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this without a MAC . You can have virtual MAC and run the simulator on that. Check out this link

[How to Virtualize iOS on a Windows 7 computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914026/how-to-virtualize-ios-on-a-windows-7-computer)